# Ubuntu server some sort of deadlock

Tags: networking, server, mount, samba

I've made some changes recently to set up my network slightly differently in the home-brew data centre. I had the machine hooked up via PowerLine but my RCD seems to heavily interfere and the speeds were entirely inadequate once I started streaming 1080p video over the line. Now I've switched to Wifi and I was getting much better speeds, but I have broken the configuration of my networking.

Currently, on boot, the machine tries to do two things. Firstly, it tries to connect to the network. This fails because the gateway is wrong (it's set to the former 192.168.0.1 gateway, but it's now on a DMZ which is on the 192.168.1.1 gateway. This (I believe) is why the network setup fails. However, I had some network shares to be mounted on the machine (it's a build server, and needs access to all sorts of junk). Mounting those network shares with a broken network configuration appears to throw the machine into some very ugly state from which it can't recover.

Sadly, booting into recovery mode doesn't seem to work. I cannot edit anything due to read only file system, and anything which re-mounts in read/write also enables networking - derp.

I don't know if it's possible to (or more to the point, how to, since it's most likely possible) mount the file system in read/write mode. I'd need to do this from a root terminal (the one you access from recovery menu) I guess. I also need a method of doing this which does not also attempt to connect network drives **or** to try mount the network share.

This is a headless machine, naturally, so everything has to be done via terminal. It smells to me like my only remaining option might be to mount the SSD in another machine and edit it manually. While this is a feasible approach, I'd like to refrain from doing it because it puts me in a difficult situation having to take another server offline (one which the Mrs is utilising right now to catch up on some Loose women over Christmas - I do treasure my manhood).

Any/all suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feeling like a bit of a wally, I discovered that it's very easy to remount and get access to write to the file system by running the following very simple command.

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Once the file system is mounted, naturally you can do whatever you need to and disable network devices etc.